# Selecting first-child anchor element in an ul

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Hi I would like to select a first-child anchor element within a ul li element so that the Anchor "All" will be selected. Code:

```html
<header>
      <h2>Clear thinking at the wrong moment can stifle <span>creativity.</span></h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Digital</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Print</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
```

header li:first-child {} targets the li item but not the text in the anchor.

header li a:first-child {} seems to target all anchor elements.
Help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try
`header ul li:first-child a {}`

Comment: To be more accurate: `.whatever > header > ul > :first-child > a`...

Comment: Really unnecessary using the `>` (child combinator), keeping it simple like Srdjan's answer is more practical in my opinion.

Comment: @Jordan Unless it is a multi-level navigation...

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. `header li:first-child a {}`

Comment: missing ul. also this question was already answered correctly.

Comment: Works without the ul as well - at least with the provided sample code :)